# Transfer function for a OP-AMP

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

[image]

Can someone tell me if the transfer function for this circuit is:

R2/[(w^2 * C^2 * R1) - jwC]

thanks

Comment: \$ V_{out} = \frac{Z1}{Z2}  \$

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a basic inverting op-amp configuration, so the transfer function will follow the form:

V_o/V_in = -Z_f/Z_i

where Z_f is the feedback impedance (R2) and Z_i is the input impedance (R1 + 1/j*w*C1).  So the transfer function will reduce to:

V_o/V_in = -R2/(R1 - j/w*C) = R2/(j/w*C - R1)

I couldn't algebraically manipulate your answer to conform to mine, so I believe the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

All you have there is an inverting opamp. The transfer function for the idealized version of it, under negative feedback is simply:

$$ H(s) = \frac{Vo(s)}{V_{in}(s)}= -\frac{Z_2(s)}{Z_1(s)}$$

Where \$Z_2(s)\$ is the impedance (in the s-domain) of the feedback network. Similarly, \$Z_1(s)\$ is the combination of the the capacitor and the resistor you have in series there.

So, 
$$ Z_2(s) = R_2$$
$$ Z_1(s) = R_1+\frac{1}{Cs}=\frac{R_1Cs+1}{Cs}$$

If you plug that into the transfer function equation you get

$$H(s)=-\frac{R_2Cs}{R_1Cs+1} $$

That's the transfer function in the s-domain.

You can go further and make the substitution, \$s=j\omega\$, then you have:

$$ H(s)=-\frac{j\omega R_2C}{j\omega R_1C+1}$$

In order to get to the form that you presented, we may want to divide everything by \$j\omega C\$ or we could have used \$Z_1(s) = R_1+\frac{1}{Cs}\$ in the original equation instead of finding the common denominator . So that now you have,

$$ H(s)=-\frac{R_2}{R_1+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1-\frac{j}{\omega C}} $$